# How to apply a microservices architecture to a voting application?

Tags: node.js, microservices

I am developing the FreeCodeCamp full stack voting application and would like to apply a microservices architecture. The user stories of the voting application are as follows:

- As an authenticated user, I can keep my polls and come back later to access them.
- As an authenticated user, I can share my polls with my friends.
- As an authenticated user, I can see the aggregate results of my polls.
- As an authenticated user, I can delete polls that I decide I don't want anymore.
- As an authenticated user, I can create a poll with any number of possible items.
- As an unauthenticated or authenticated user, I can see and vote on everyone's polls.

I am conceptualizing an architecture and come up with this:

[image: Concept Architecture Voting App]

The application is composed of 6 microservices:
1. UI
2. Aggregator
3. Authorization (login, logout)
4. Social Media (sharing)
5. Polls (with db)
6. Users (with db)

Curious how a developer having built microservices would break down these user stories into microservices. Thank you!

Comment: What is the `Aggregator`?

Comment: The aggregator is a central access point for all client requests. It can be used for balancing load as well.

Comment: So, an API Gateway

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have already done a good job spliting the application in microservices. Every one of the has its own persistence and they should communicate with a technology agnostic protocol or by asynchronous events.

I would do it pretty much like you did. Maybe `Auth` should be splitted into `Authentication` (i.e. using a stateless jwt)  and `Authorization` (+its own database).

The `Authentication` would ensure that the User is who he says it is.

The `Authorization` would verify that a User may modify only his own polls.

Comment: Hey Constantin,

Question: how would the authentication and authorization services look like?

I imagine I could take care of authorization with JWT. A JWT is created upon login and verified every time a non-public route is requested.

I imagine authentication to take care of the login. I am not sure whether the entire /login route belongs in the authentication service or it would be a better idea to include /login in the users api and request the password hash comparisson from the authentication service.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the `Authentication's` responsibility? To login a user and to check if a user is logged-in. The `Users` does not have this responsibility so a `/login` endpoint in `Users` would be misleading. I would add a `/verify-user-password` in `Users` microservice.

Comment: So would the login route be part of the authentication service?

Comment: Yes, that would be the most correct split. I don't fully understand your domain. But what exactly is `Users`? This term seems a technical one, from the developers world. Or is from the Authentication bounded context?

Comment: "So would the login route be part of the authentication service? " - yes

Comment: Okay and when would the "/verify-user-password" route be used if the /login route is already part of the authentication service?

Users is a CRUD microservice taking care of the user data provided by members of the voting application.

Comment: What kind of user data? User credentials? User names/firstnames/middlename?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165466/discussion-between-wasbeer-and-constantin-galbenu).

Answer (score 1):

Polls Module is as of now seems to be responsible for creating a polls, conducting polls, managing poll session (given that you might have more than one question to answer in your poll) and keeping track of results.

Alright, you might have just one db to keep all of these things but they have separate concerns and (if you scale this up) different biz teams managing it. So I would suggest you can split polls alongs those lines. (They might be helpful when you start scaling it up)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Anunay.

Would you divide the polls microservice into four separate ones with the same db?

1. creating-polls <--> db1
2. conducting-polls <--> db1
3. managing-poll-session 
4. tracking-results <--> db1

Comment: No, I will not suggest that. You can create poll in once service and then for conducting polls needs a question to polled which could be fetched from service1 and can record user responses. Tracking result can source data from the service 2 via events sourcing may be and compute the real time results and do other analysis.